# Does "Do you have some Chinese in you?" refer to parents or to interests?

Tags: meaning, questions

> "Do you have some Chinese in you?"

This means, do you have some Chinese blood in your body because your parents or grandparents are Chinese?

or

do you have any interest in Chinese culture or spirits?

Which meaning is true?

Comment: It is the start of a very bad pickup line.

Answer (score 22):

The first one.  It's important to note that this can be a personal/intrusive question in many situations.

"Do you have some Chinese in you?" could be rephrased as "Do you have Chinese ancestry?".

Answer (score 4):

99% of the time it means "your features/skin colour look slightly Chinese".

Comment: While not the literal meaning, this is often the implied meaning to such a question at least in the U.S. The implication could be "You have some sort of feature I associate with looking Chinese. Are you?"

Answer (score -4):

It can mean either one. Just as can

> Are you part Chinese?

Both expressions ask about "Chinese ancestry" but by extension can ask about interests because of the idea that typically only people with Chinese ancestry are interested in or know about certain things.